# CALayer equivalent in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13

`UIViews` are known to be layer backed, but not sure about `SwiftUI` View. Is there a concept of layer in `SwiftUI` which can be added as sublayer, animated, everything you could do with `CALayer`?

Comment: Not sure for this... but from the example codes, i have seen.. it looks like they removed the layer concept..

Comment: If they have removed CALayer, then hell lot of more work may be needed in SwiftUI to supply all the functionality. No idea how it would interface with Metal/OpenGL.

Comment: Remember you can always wrap UIKit objects in a SwiftUI view; one of Apple's examples shows this using an `MKMapView`  - but there is a lot you can do natively too. See https://youtu.be/wBcLFEtZ8A4 For example

Comment: @Paulw11 that's a good thing to know but then the question is if SwiftUI can not substitute UIKit fully, then does that make development task with it anymore easy (if not difficult)?

Comment: I haven't really played with it a lot yet, but so far it looks almost like it will be a lot better; You can work visually in the canvas or in code, with the code or canvas being updated in real-time as you do.  Will SwiftUI do everything that anyone will ever need?  Probably not, but either did Interface Builder.  Interface Builder had problems with version control, particularly when working with teams.  Programmatic UI is slower to develop as you need to keep running your code to see if it is correct; SwiftUI seems to address both of these issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the "Building Custom Views with SwiftUI" talk, they demonstrated that Views and Drawing models/interfaces have essentially been combined under the hood in the framework. Therefore, a View has layer like attributes but built onto the View itself rather than a layer abstraction.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/

Answer (score 0):

After checking the `SwiftUI`'s all methods by jumping to defination of `View` like this:

[image]

In that file, i can see that all UIControls, all methods, which as developer we can access are listed there. Here, i found that there is no any layer like concept. But all the properties of layer - like cornerRadius, borderWidth, borderColor, shadow etc all are already defined there. So i think there are less probable chance of having such concept in `SwiftUI`.

Still not sure for my this answer.

Comment: we just don't know what's under the hood